# fadeOut Validation messages Jquery

Tags: jquery, validation, plugins, response, fadeout

How do I use the jquery fadeOut function to fade out the validation response message "this field is required" at this [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Nick_B/kmJ87/). I just want the messages to pop up (not fade in) then fade out slowly over maybe 3 seconds.

This is the js that controls the Validation plugin:

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#commentForm').validate({
            submitHandler: function(form) {
                $.ajax({
                    type: 'POST',
                    url: 'process.php',
                    data: $(this).serialize(),
                    success: function(returnedData) {
                        $('#commentForm').append(returnedData);
                    }
                });         
                return false;
            },
            errorPlacement: function(error, element) {
                  error.insertAfter( element).position({
                      my:'right top',
                      at:'right top',
                      of:element          
                  });
               }        
        }); 
    });
```

Thank you for your input.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All you need to do is call fadeOut on the `error` argument in `errorPlacement()`:

```
           errorPlacement: function(error, element) {
              error.insertAfter( element).position({
                  my:'right top',
                  at:'right top',
                  of:element          
              });
              error.fadeOut(3000);
           }
```

Working example: http://jsfiddle.net/kmJ87/4/

Comment: Hi thank you @maxedison. Could you help me understand why the fadeOut only works on the first validation response? The second time the validatoin is triggered, the message does not fadeOut.

Comment: Fadeout works but will click on submit again these function is called.

Answer (score 2):

If you wish to make the timed fadeout effect run multiple times, you need to remove the error element as soon it disappears:

```
errorPlacement: function(error, element) {
    error.insertAfter( element).position({
    my:'right top',
        at:'right top',
            of:element          
        });
        // here the magic happens, we remove the element, forcing the errorPlacement callback to be run every time
        error.fadeOut(3000, function() { $(this).remove(); });
    }
```